# jQuery DataTable With Sum Total And Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am new to jQuery and have been working on a project that uses DataTables to display and sort data.  So far I have most of the features I need working, but my script that gives the total of a column is having issues with my buttons script.

Here is my total script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#reportTable').DataTable({
    "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
      var api = this.api(),
        data;

      // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
      var intVal = function(i) {
        return typeof i === 'string' ?
          i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
          typeof i === 'number' ?
          i : 0;
      };

      // Total over all pages
      total = api.column(4).data().reduce(function(a, b) {
        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
      }, 0);

      // Total over all filtered pages
      if (api.column(4, {
          search: 'applied'
        }).data().length) {
        pageTotal = api.column(4, {
          search: 'applied'
        }).data().reduce(function(a, b) {
          return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        });
      } else {
        pageTotal = 0;
      }

      $(api.column(4).footer()).html(pageTotal.toFixed(2));

      // Update footer
      $(api.column(4).footer()).html(pageTotal.toFixed(2) + ' hours ( ' + total.toFixed(2) + ' total hours)');
    }
  });
});
```

Here is my buttons script:

```js
$('#reportTable').DataTable({
  dom: 'Blfrtip',
  buttons: [{
      extend: 'pdf',
      className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-file',
      title: 'Report',
      filename: 'Report',
      exportOptions: {
        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
      }
    },
    {
      extend: 'excel',
      className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt',
      title: 'Report',
      filename: 'Report',
      exportOptions: {
        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
      }
    },
    {
      extend: 'copy',
      className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate',
      exportOptions: {
        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
      }
    },
    {
      extend: 'print',
      className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-print',
      title: 'Report',
      text: 'Print',
      exportOptions: {
        modifier: {
          page: 'current'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

I realize that it is an initialization issue (since I am initializing twice), but my attempt at fixing it is not working.  It seems like I should be able to do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#reportTable').DataTable({
    "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
      var api = this.api(),
        data;

      // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
      var intVal = function(i) {
        return typeof i === 'string' ?
          i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
          typeof i === 'number' ?
          i : 0;
      };

      // Total over all pages
      total = api.column(4).data().reduce(function(a, b) {
        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
      }, 0);

      // Total over all filtered pages
      if (api.column(4, {
          search: 'applied'
        }).data().length) {
        pageTotal = api.column(4, {
          search: 'applied'
        }).data().reduce(function(a, b) {
          return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        });
      } else {
        pageTotal = 0;
      }

      $(api.column(4).footer()).html(pageTotal.toFixed(2));

      // Update footer
      $(api.column(4).footer()).html(pageTotal.toFixed(2) + ' hours ( ' + total.toFixed(2) + ' total hours)');
    }
  }, {
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    buttons: [{
        extend: 'pdf',
        className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-file',
        title: 'Report',
        filename: 'Report',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'excel',
        className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt',
        title: 'Report',
        filename: 'Report',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'copy',
        className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate',
        exportOptions: {
          columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        }
      },
      {
        extend: 'print',
        className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-print',
        title: 'Report',
        text: 'Print',
        exportOptions: {
          modifier: {
            page: 'current'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

...but that isn't working for me.  I am not receiving any errors, but whichever script is on "top" runs and the second part is ignored.  Can someone explain the logic behind this to me?  I am struggling with the syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate your effort but it will be nice if you can add a working fiddle of it. something like this http://jsfiddle.net/rmcmaster/bbLjzspf/22/

Comment: The problem is that this is linked to an SQL database and the razor syntax throws off my fiddle attempts.  I will see what I can do.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/l337method/9tjoeg8v/3/

Sorry.  It is a rush job because I don't want to waste too much of your time.  The addition is working on there currently, but the buttons are not appearing.  if you swap their order in the script then the buttons show...but the sum functionality disappears. >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Issue was with the brackets

I will keep it short

This is correct format

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "paging":   false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info":     false
} );
```

What you were trying was this

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    {"paging":   false},
    {"ordering": false},
    {"info":     false}
} );
```

Datatable will not complain for above code but will pick last one I guess.

Full code

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#reportTable').DataTable({

            dom: 'Blfrtip',
            buttons: [{
                    extend: 'pdf',
                    className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-file',
                    title: 'Report',
                    filename: 'Report',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt',
                    title: 'Report',
                    filename: 'Report',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'copy',
                    className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-print',
                    title: 'Report',
                    text: 'Print',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            page: 'current'
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
                var api = this.api(),
                    data;

                // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                var intVal = function(i) {
                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                        i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                        typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
                };

                // Total over all pages
                total = api
                    .column(5)
                    .data()
                    .reduce(function(a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }, 0);

                // Total over all filtered pages
                if (api.column(5, {
                        search: 'applied'
                    }).data().length) {
                    pageTotal = api
                        .column(5, {
                            search: 'applied'
                        })
                        .data()
                        .reduce(function(a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        });
                } else {
                    pageTotal = 0;
                }

                $(api.column(5).footer()).html(
                    pageTotal.toFixed(2)
                );

                // Update footer
                $(api.column(5).footer()).html(
                    pageTotal.toFixed(2) + ' hours ( ' + total.toFixed(2) + ' total hours)'
                );
            },

        });
    }
);
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tjoeg8v/12/)

Comment: That did it.  Thank you, sir.  That was driving me nuts. :D

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I haven't test this yet. I will be soon and update this answer.

First, I would advice to reorganize the code in pieces so its easy to spot issues.
I just did that and found out that there were some code discrepancies.

Below is a clean up of the last chuck of code you provided.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#reportTable').DataTable({
    "footerCallback": footerCallback, 
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    buttons: buttons
  });
});

function footerCallback(row, data, start, end, display) {
      var api = this.api();
     
      // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
      var intVal = function(i) {
        return (typeof i === 'string') ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                                         (typeof i === 'number') ? i : 0;
      };


      var sumFn = function(a, b) { return intVal(a) + intVal(b); }
      
      // Total over all pages
      var total = api.column(4).data().reduce(sumFn, 0);
      
      var lengthOpts = { search: 'applied' };
      var length = api.column(4, lengthOpts).data().length;

      // Total over all filtered pages
      if (length) {
        pageTotal = api.column(4, lengthOpts).data().reduce(sumFn);
      } else {
        pageTotal = 0;
      }

      $(api.column(4).footer()).html(pageTotal.toFixed(2));

      // Update footer
      var footerStr = pageTotal.toFixed(2) 
                    + ' hours ( ' 
                    + total.toFixed(2) 
                    + ' total hours)';
      $(api.column(4).footer()).html(footerStr);
  }
  
  function buttons(){
    return [
        {
          extend: 'pdf',
          className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-file',
          title: 'Report',
          filename: 'Report',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
          }
        },
        {
          extend: 'excel',
          className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt',
          title: 'Report',
          filename: 'Report',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
          }
        },
        {
          extend: 'copy',
          className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
          }
        },
        {
          extend: 'print',
          className: 'green glyphicon glyphicon-print',
          title: 'Report',
          text: 'Print',
          exportOptions: {
            modifier: {
              page: 'current'
            }
          }
        }
      ];
  }
```

From l337method:

> That also worked! Thank you very much for showing me how to reorganize the code. I'll be sure to do that going forward. – l337method

Comment: That also worked!  Thank you very much for showing me how to reorganize the code.  I'll be sure to do that going forward.

Comment: @l337method I am glad that I managed to help you out. if you could vote positive in the answer, I would appreciate it.